# How can export georeferenced coordinates in a dwg cad file

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, autocad, geo, cad

I have an Autocad dwg file where each point on the plane has an associated UTM coordinate.
Is it possible to extract these coordinates using python or c# (the programming language really doesn't matter)?
I could pass you an example file if necessary.

All the information will be helpful, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

try to save it as DXF and then you can open it in text editor.